# Gradle Obfuscade and Publish Artifact

Tags: gradle, publish, nexus

I am trying to publish an obfuscated JAR created by the Gradle ProGuard Plugin to a Maven repository. I've learned much about Gradle configurations, variants and artifacts over the last days, but I seem to be unable to make this work. I believe the relevant documentation is the one here.

I tried gradle.build script below, but I get:

```
Cannot get property 'obfuscatedJar' on null object.
```

I tried also to specify the artifact inside the publishing declaration, but didn't work.

How can I publish an obfuscated jar?

What is this artifacts declaration in gradle?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.guardsquare:proguard-gradle:7.3.0"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools:gradle_publish:10.0.5"
    }
}
plugins{
    id 'com.install4j.gradle' version '10.0.5'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'signing'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'distribution'
apply plugin: 'com.install4j.gradle'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'signing'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {...
}

compileJava{
    sourceCompatibility = '11'
    targetCompatibility = '11'
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls',
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.graphics',
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.web',
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.swing'
        ]
    }
}

jar {
    archiveName ="dbs.jar"
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.wisecoders.dbs.DbSchema'
        attributes 'Specification-Version': "$version"
        attributes 'Specification-Vendor': "Wise Coders"
        attributes 'Implementation-Vendor-Id': "dbschema.com"
        attributes 'Implementation-Vendor': "Wise Coders"
        attributes 'Implementation-Version': new Date().format( 'yyMMdd' )
    }
}

task proguard(type:proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask, dependsOn:['clean','jar']) {
    configuration 'resources/install/proguard.txt'
    libraryjars files(configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect())
    // CHECK IN gradle.properties org.gradle.java.home.
    libraryjars "${System.env.JAVA_HOME}/jmods/"

    injars "$buildDir/libs/dbs.jar"
    outjars "$buildDir/app-libs/dbschema.jar"
}

install4j {
    installDir = file(project.ext.install4jDir)
}


group = "com.wisecoders"

java {
    withJavadocJar()
}
javadoc {
    options.addBooleanOption('html5', true)
}
def obfuscatedJar = file("build/app-libs/dbschema.jar")
artifacts {
    archives javadocJar obfuscatedJar
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = 'dbschema'
            from components.java
            versionMapping {
                usage('java-api') {
                    fromResolutionOf('runtimeClasspath')
                }
                usage('java-runtime') {
                    fromResolutionResult()
                }
            }
            pom {
                name = 'DbSchema'
                description = 'DbSchema Database Management GUI'
                url = 'https://dbschema.com'
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name = 'Perpetual Fallback License'
                        url = 'https://dbschema.com'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id = 'wisecoders'
                        name = 'Wise Coders GmbH'
                        email = 'support@dbschema.com.com'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection = 'scm:git:git://github.com/wise-coders/dbschema'
                    developerConnection = 'scm:git:ssh://github.com/wise-coders/dbschema'
                    url = 'https://github.com/wise-coders/dbschema'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "OSSRH"
            url = "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
            credentials {
                username = project.properties["sonatypeUsername"]
                password = project.properties["sonatypePassword"]
            }
        }
    }
}
signing {
    sign publishing.publications.mavenJava
}
```